# How can credits (like closing credits) be found?

Tags: production

Is there any way other than watching a movie or trusting IMDB to see the credits (such as closing credits) of any movie?

Comment: What are you actually looking for? The reason I ask is that some or all of the cast and crew is not always listed in the closing credits, but rather in the opening. Or are you actually wanting to know about "crazy credits" or after the credits additional scenes, whether bloopers or tie-ins to (potential)sequels.

Comment: @Kevin Howell: Good question. Where ARE these things archived?

Comment: @CGCampbell I'm actually asking about credits in general of any movie. They seem to be hard to find if they aren't on IMDB which they aren't always or at least not all of the credits are. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that the industry itself must store this kind of data somewhere since this is a practical necessity (e.g. people need to be paid residuals,...). There is for instance the [Motion Picture Credits Database](http://www.oscars.org/research-preservation/resources-databases/mpc.html):

> Every year, as part of the Academy Awards process, the Academy gathers
>   credits from films hoping to qualify for awards. To these credits,
>   compiled and verified by the film's producer or distributor, we add
>   credits from other films released in Los Angeles County, using
>   research materials from the Academy's Margaret Herrick Library.
>
> In addition to personal credits, MPC records index production and
>   releasing companies, MPAA ratings, running times, Los Angeles release
>   dates, color, language, source authors and source material, all of
>   which are searchable.
>
> The credits in the MPC database were originally collected and printed
>   in the Academy publication Annual Index to Motion Picture Credits. The
>   Index started in 1934 as the Screen Achievement Records Bulletin, when
>   the Writers Branch of the Academy began publishing a bulletin of
>   screen authorship records.

... and the Official Screen Credits for Academy Awards Consideration (same page, I'm not going to copy-paste the entire description).

[This page](http://www.lib.berkeley.edu/MRC/filmstudies/searchabledbs.html) mentions several databases, some are only available to UCB users.